# write ansible-playbook for webservices

Tags: api, ansible

How do I use POST with Ansbile

```
curl -k -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json"-u user:A231212123432 "https://www.example.com"
```

Request Body

```
{
"a":"1"
"b":"2"
"c":"3"
}
```

Comment: I think you question is more like, how to use POST with `curl`?

Comment: I want to convert a curl command to ansible uri

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/uri_module.html) it would work like this:

```
- url: https://www.example.com
  method: POST
  user: user
  password: A231212123432
  HEADER_Content-Type: "application/json"
  body: '{ "a":"1" "b":"2" "c":"3" }'
```